# VBS or batch for identifying folders with more than two words

Tags: batch, vbscript

I have a series of ~10,000 folders, and most of them have two words (a first name and a last name) that need to be swapped. That's the easy part. The part where I struggle is to programmatically identify the folder names that have more than two words as the positioning of the last name needs to be treated differently. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You're trying to rename a bunch of folders?  I would start with VBS (it will be the more powerful of the two, if your other consideration was a batch file).  For an initial script, maybe find some example code to loop through each folder name.  For each folder, parse the name accordingly using the appropriate delimiter for your folder name structure (space, comma, etc.).  If the folder names all have the same fixed delimiter structure that may be a lot easier than resorting to a regular expression (RegExp).

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

You could do this quite easily with [JREN.BAT - a regular expression renaming utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081). JREN.BAT is pure script (hybrid batch/JScript) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward - no 3rd party exe file required. Full documentation is available from the command line via `jren /?`, or `jren /??` for paged help.

You don't say exactly how you want to handle the three names, so I will provide a couple examples. For each example, I add the `/T` test mode option that simply lists the changes that would be made. Remove the `/T` option and the renaming will actually take place. These examples will only rename folders that have exactly 2 or 3 "words".

**A B ==> B A** *or* **A B C ==> C A B**

```
jren "^(\S+)\s*(\s\S+)?\s+(\S+)$" "$3 $1$2" /d /t
```

**A B ==> B A** *or* **A B C ==> A C B**

```
jren "^(\S+\s)?\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)$" "$1$3 $2" /d /t
```

If the three name format is entirely different than two, you can either run two separate commands, one for two names, and one for three, or you can add the `/J` option and put user supplied JScript in the replace argument to get arbitrarily complex results.

Comment: Wow!!!  It will take me weeks before I will really understand this JREN batch file.  Thanks!

Comment: @jvbelg You should accept that answer then!! What do you mean by "`It will take me weeks before I will really understand this JREN batch file`"? Is it really that hard... LOL